# add interfaces to a second OSPF process in cisco

Tags: networking, cisco

I am trying to create two OSPF processes on the same router, I configure both using the same commands but only the one with the lower process id takes the interfaces and works, the second one has no interfaces!

the OSPF configuration takes place after assigning IP addresses to involved interfaces.

the commands I used:

```
router ospf 1
network [my network range] area 1
```

and the same for ospf 2

any idea how I can add interfaces to the 2nd OSPF process?

Answer (score 0):

Running two OSPF processes on the same interface is not supported and does not   really make any sense to me from a protocol perspective.  You'll need to configure the networks such that the two processes are running on different interfaces.